# How to design microservices where I need to scale up the specific service with its own DB?

Tags: microservices

I am relatively new to DB, Design and Microservices. Lets consider in a ecommerce app, i create three services as below each with its own DBs.
products
customers
orders

Consider I am running single container for each of services.
Now suppose I am getting huge numbers of orders and I want to scale up the orders service, then the new containers are created on different nodes in Kubernetes or Docker Swarm. How will the two containers of the same service use the same DB instance?
What is the way to design this. I might be missing some basics. Any pointers will also help.

Comment: The database should not be *in* the service, it should be outside of it. Also starting with microservices is a really bad idea. It's not a good pattern except for some really specific situations.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling a service to use multiple instances is effectively the same as launching the same application multiple times. There is no effective difference between running two containers in Kubernetes and starting the application twice on your local machine.

If the database connection parameters are identical, each service instance will connect to the same database. Of course, the database server would need to be completely independent from the service, so every service instance can share the database. You could think of the database as another service offering.